# Calling a FORTRAN exe file using R

Tags: r, fortran, exe

I don't know any Fortran and I am trying to run a Fortran exe file from Rstudio.
I have a Fortran exe file(called psibtflCT.exe) that interacts with the user to take an input file (called Psib_future.IN).

I tried the  command below but it fails to prompt the user for the input file and instead just gives the following message:

```
system2("psibtflCT.exe", "Psib_future.IN")
 Enter name of file on which input info is stored
  Enter 0 if the default name, PSIB.IN, was used

forrtl: severe (24): end-of-file during read, unit -4, file CONIN$
Image              PC        Routine            Line        Source             
PSIBTF~1.EXE       0041EE39  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown

Incrementally linked image--PC correlation disabled.
```

As noted above, the command I was advised to use was:

```
system2("psibtflCT.exe", "Psib_future.IN")
```

How do I get system2 to prompt the user for the input file after running the exe file?

UPDATE: I also tried this:

```
shell(" cd C:\\Users\\S. Sundar\\Downloads && (echo psibtflCT.exe && echo Psib_future.IN", intern=TRUE)
```

Here is the message I get:

```
character(0)
attr(,"status")
[1] 1
Warning message:
In system(cmd, intern = intern, wait = wait | intern, show.output.on.console = wait,  :
  running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c  cd C:\Users\S. Sundar\Downloads && (echo psibtflCT.exe && echo Psib_future.IN' had status 1
```

Comment: Looks like you need to redirect your stdin. Try `<`, if it works in MS Windows.

Comment: Could you show me the syntax for using shell() @dww Also yes I was told its a compiled file, originally from Fortran

Comment: @VladimirF Could you show me syntax for this please - I was just given that one line of code "system2 etc etc", so I don't understand what you mean

Comment: No, I never used `system2` and I do not work in Windows, I just play games there.

Comment: `system2("psibtflCT.exe < Psib_future.IN")` ?

Comment: @BenBolker no, that does't work :(, I don't get any output